# Recalcitrant StaleObjectStateException problem using Spring Retry

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-retry

I am using Spring retry to handle retrying a given worker method in the case of unexpected minor errors.  Here is my simplified current code:

```
public class WorkerClass {
    @Autowired
    protected MyJpaRepository myJpaRepository;

    @Retryable(
        value = {Exception.class}, maxAttempts=3, backoff=@Backoff(5000))
    public void doSomething(RandomDTO dto) throws Exception {
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            // perform the task
            success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Something went wrong");
        }

        if (!success) {
            // create logEntity for failure using DTO
            MyEntity entity = myJpaRespository.save(logEntity);
            // update DTO using auto generated ID from entity
            throw new Exception("Give it another try!");
        }
        else {
            // create logEntity for success using DTO
            myJpaRespository.save(logEntity);
        }
    }

    @Recover
    public void recover(Exception ex, RandomDTO dto) {
        LOGGER.error("fatal error; all retries failed");
            // create logEntity for failure using DTO
        myJpaRespository.save(logEntity); // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
    }
}
```

What I am observing is that the initial and all subsequent tries to the `doSomething()` method complete without error.  But, when the `recover()` method gets called, there is a JPA exception when trying to write to the repository.

The stack trace contains:

> optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

My understanding of this problem is that Hibernate is, for some reason, maintaining a lock on the entity made in the `doSomething()` method.  Then, we the `recover()` method gets hit by the Spring retry framework, the update fails, because something else has a lock on that record.  But, I don't understand *why* this is happening.  Can someone shed light on this?

Comment: Where does logEntity come from. where is it created / fetched from db? Can you add entity class of it?

Comment: Adding the code is not really relevant to the question.  The entity is generated using the DTO (which also contains the primary key ID field).  So, whenever we need to write the entity using the DTO, we create the entity object from scratch, and then save it using the JPA repository.  This approach _almost_ works, except for the `recover()` method.

Comment: @Maciej Do you know of some way to tell Hibernate/JPA to stop tracking a given entity?

Comment: Optimistic locking is managed when you have a @Version field on your entity. Thats why I was intered in the defintion of that entity..

Comment: Yes, there is a field with `@Version` annotation.  Why does that matter here?

Comment: It should not matter when you create a new entity with unique Id as no other transaction may be wobling with it. Thats why I was also interested in the way you set-up that entity before save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimistic locking is a strategy which is enabled in JPA by the usage of `@Version` annotated field. It is a great strategy to use as it eliminates all the physical locking problems caused by the usage of pessimistic locking method.

In your case, I have the following observations:

**1)** The problem is caused when inserting into a LOG type table. I think that application should never contain any updating logic in this case and thus `@Version` is obsolete and unnecessary (even if that is the general strategy used in your application).

**2)** The general principle when it comes to saving logs in the database is to run the save in a completely new transaction. We do not want our program to fail (and the parent transaction) because of some logging issue. That's why I would suggest the following:

```
@Recover
@Transactional(propagation = PropagationType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void recover(Exception ex, RandomDTO dto) {
    LOGGER.error("fatal error; all retries failed");
        // create logEntity for failure using DTO
    myJpaRespository.save(logEntity); // EXCEPTION OCCURS HERE
}
```

Comment: While this was not an exact fix for my problem, your suggestion that `@Version` is the culprit was literally spot on, and led me to the right fix.  The exact problem was that I was trying to persist an entity whose `@Version` value was out of sync with what was already in the Hibernate cache/database.  The fix was to always make sure that the version reflects the latest revision.